# Busca em Vetor de Ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, estrutura-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Considere um tipo que representa um funcionário de uma empresa, definido pela estrutura a seguir:

```c
typedef struct funcionario Funcionario;
struct funcionario {
  char nome[81];     // Nome do funcionário
  float valor_hora;  // Valor da hora de trabalho em Reais
  int horas_mes;     // Horas trabalhadas em um mês
};
```

Escreva uma função que faça uma busca binária em um vetor de ponteiros para o tipo `Funcionario`, cujos elementos estão em ordem alfabética dos nomes dos funcionários. Esta função deve receber como parâmetros o número de funcionários, o vetor e o nome do funcionário que se deseja buscar, e deve ter como valor de retorno um ponteiro para o registro do funcionário procurado. Se não houver um funcionário com o nome procurado, a função deve retornar `NULL`. A função deve obedecer ao seguinte protótipo:

```c
Funcionario* busca (int n, Funcionario** v, char* nome);
```

Segue meu código, não encontro o erro.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct funcionario Funcionario;

struct funcionario {
  char nome[81];
  float valor_hora;
  int horas_mes;
};

static int comp(char* a, Funcionario* b) { return strcmp(a, b->nome); }

Funcionario* busca(int n, Funcionario** v, char* nome) {
  int i, ini, fim, meio, cmp;
  ini = 0;
  fim = n - 1;
  while (ini <= fim) {
    meio = (ini + fim) / 2;
    cmp = comp(nome, v[meio]);
    if (cmp < 0)
      fim = meio - 1;
    else if (cmp > 0)
      ini = meio + 1;
    else
      return v[meio];
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  int i, n;
  char name[85];
  scanf("%d", &n);
  Funcionario* a[n];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Funcionario* vet = malloc(sizeof(Funcionario));
    a[i] = vet;
    scanf("%s", vet->nome);
    scanf("%d", &vet->horas_mes);
    scanf("%f", &vet->valor_hora);
  }
  scanf("%s", name);
  Funcionario* resp = busca(n, a, name);
  printf("%s\n", resp->nome);
  printf("%d %.1f\n", resp->horas_mes, resp->valor_hora);
}
```

Comment: Você está partindo do pressuposto que a entrada de dados será em ordem alfabética mas não está fazendo nenhum tipo de validação desta obrigatoriedade.

Comment: [Desde que os valores fornecidos estejam ordenados o código funciona corretamente](https://ideone.com/YiHmKb). Agora pessoalmente não recomendo ler montes de valores sem indicar ao utilizador o que ele deve inserir. Até mesmo só para si a nivel de teste fica facil de falhar. Falta também a inclusão de `<string.h>` que pode quebrar em alguns casos.